# How to map with different text in the file

Tags: python

Code is below

I need to replace the text inside the file with the dictionary

- abc.txt contain `this is abc file`
- cde.txt contain `this is cde file`

```
    {'abc':'123', 'cde':'456'}
    all_files = ['abc.txt','cde.txt']
    out_files = ['abc_output.txt','cde_output.txt']
    read_dict = {}
    for in_f, out_f in zip(all_files, out_files):
        #print (in_f, out_f)
        with open(in_f,'r') as read_file:
            lines = read_file.readlines()
        with open(out_f,'w+') as write_file:
             #write_file.writelines(lines)
            print(lines)
```

My out

```
['This is abc file']
['This is cde file']
```

Expected out

```
['This is 123 file']
['This is 456 file']
```

Comment: What does `abc.txt` and `cde.txt` contain ?

Comment: you do nothing with lines, how is it supposed to translate any value if you dont use the dictionary you created for translation?

Comment: @YounessSaadna added

Comment: The hard part is figuring out exactly what you mean by "replacing the text." E.g., does `'abcde'` turn into `'123de'`, `'ab456'`, or something else? Can a mapping span multiple lines?

Comment: @HansMusgrave right now its not there, but future it might be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mapping = {'abc':'123', 'cde':'456'}
all_files = ['abc.txt','cde.txt']
out_files = ['abc_output.txt','cde_output.txt']
read_dict = {}
for in_f, out_f in zip(all_files, out_files):
    #print (in_f, out_f)
    with open(in_f,'r') as read_file:
        lines = read_file.readlines()
    with open(out_f,'w+') as write_file:
        for line in lines:
            for key in mapping:
                line = line.replace(key, mapping[key])
            #write_file.writelines(line)
```

Comment: please dont copy same answer your answer is working fine

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok to not split word by word like https://stackoverflow.com/a/63420151/5725669, you can also go with this

```
mapping = {'abc':'123', 'cde':'456'}
all_files = ['abc.txt','cde.txt']
out_files = ['abc_output.txt','cde_output.txt']
read_dict = {}
for in_f, out_f in zip(all_files, out_files):
    with open(in_f,'r') as read_file:
        lines = read_file.readlines()
    with open(out_f,'w+') as write_file:         
        for line in lines:    
            for key in mapping:
                line = line.replace(key, mapping[key])
            #write_file.writelines(line)
```

Comment: stack link to this question only